# remove caps lock from bar code when scanning

Tags: barcode-scanner

I have an Intermec CK3 scanner and when the user scans a barcode it automatically gets the code in uppercase. Is there any setting to disable this?

PS: User is trying to scan a password

Comment: This is most likely a property of the type of bar code, and how it's encoded. What type of bar code are you scanning? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS1

Comment: we tried to use 3of9 barcode to make a label with user and passwords in excel